# Error al ejecutar DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE en Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy ejecutando `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` para enviar un mensaje desde un procedimiento y estoy intentando mostrar la información de depuración de lo que contiene una variable de tipo `BFILE`

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_FILEUPLOAD_XML IS

v_dir       gzvcatg.gzvcatg_desc11%TYPE;
l_dir       VARCHAR2(35);
l_fil       VARCHAR2(30) := 'ES0000251446027471.xml'; 
l_loc       BFILE;

BEGIN

        l_loc := BFILENAME(v_dir,l_fil);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_loc); 

END;
```

Al momento de ejecutar mi procedimiento y esperar en log una respuesta por parte de `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe a que se debe el error y como corregirlo

Comment: el parametro es un varchar2??? [documentacion](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67327)

Comment: La variable `l_loc` es de tipo `BFILE`

Comment: y bfile = varchar2?

Comment: A que te refieres con que le asigne `varchar2` a `BFILE` ?

Comment: Me refiero a que leiste la documentacion? El tipo bfile no es el mismo tipo que el varchar2, de ahi podria venir tu problema

Comment: Y como logro imprimir o que me muestre en consola lo que contiene la variable `l_loc` sin tener que cambiar el tipo de dato

Comment: Ah ni idea.. yo solo te señale el error que describe el problema en tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

La función BFILENAME lo que devuelve es un "localizador".

No es el contenido del archivo.

Debe usar en un LOOP-END LOOP los procedimientos del package DBMS_LOB para cargar iteractivamente en una variable VARCHAR2 cierta cantidad de bytes del archivo para mostrarlo por  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.